# Python Pynput release and press

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, mouseevent, pynput

Hi i want to make a script that prints "Released" when i release my left mouse button.
The same for "pressed"

```
import time
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode

mouse = Controller()
time.sleep(3)

while True:
    if mouse.press(Button.left):
        print("Pressed")
        # mouse.press(Button.left)
        # mouse.release(Button.left)
    if mouse.release(Button.left):
        print("released")
```

Comment: [Monitoring the mouse](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html) is everything you need.

Comment: worked thanks for help !